# Not able to execute all commands in my batch file

Tags: batch-file, npm, apiconnect

Below is my batch script :

```
@echo off

cd "C:\Users\SXR1176\AppData\Roaming\npm"

set /p Product= Enter Product : 
set /p Organization= Enter Organization :  
set /p Server= Enter Server: 

echo Product %Product%  

echo Organization %Organization%  

echo Server %Server%  

cmd /k apic login 

cmd 

apic drafts:pull %Product%  --organization %Organization% --server %Server% 

pause
```

The output of the above batch file is below :

```
Enter Product : sendfax-from-dev-faxutilitywsdl-product:1.0.0

Enter Organization :  demoOrg

Enter Server: dummyserver.com

Product sendfax-from-dev-faxutilitywsdl-product:1.0.0

Organization demo

Server dummyserver.com

Enter the API Connect server
? Server: dummyserver.com
? Username: username
? Password (typing will be hidden) *******
Logged into dev-apic.humana.com successfully

C:\Users\SXR1176\AppData\Roaming\npm>
```

I see after the apic login command , the next command (apic drafts) is not executed at all . Could you please let me know what is happening .

Comment: It didn't work b/c you basically started a new shell right after the login (i.e. you ran `cmd`). That would cause the script to stop and wait for the user to do something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you do the `cmd /k` and the odd `cmd` but give this a try:

```
@echo off
cd  /d "C:\Users\SXR1176\AppData\Roaming\npm"

set /p "product=Enter Product : "
set /p "organization=Enter Organization :  "
set /p "server=Enter Server: "

echo Product %product%
echo Organization %organization%
echo Server %server% 

call apic login
call apic drafts:pull %product%  --organization %organization% --server %server% 
pause
```

Then that said. I am a bit uncertain about what needs to happen here. I do not have apic so I cannot replicate the issue so let us see how it goes with the answer. I suspect that apic might be outside of the cmd scope.

Comment: thank you for your response Gerhard .

Basically before executing the apic login or apic drafts , I need to be in this directory --> C:\Users\SXR1176\AppData\Roaming\npm .

apic login will login to the API connect server (need to give the server name , username and password) . Once I have logged in , I want to pull a product from the API connect server .